# Thread 1: "attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update"

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I just want to refresh the `.stock` section. Because `.filter` section seems to be fixed. I'm making a request to the API every second. When I press the UIMenu button in the Filter cell, the UIMenu is closed when the tableView reload function works. So I just want to refresh the .stock section. When I do this I get an error.

**Error:**
Thread 1: "attempt to delete section 1, but there are only 1 sections before the update"

**TableView Sections:**

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let sectionTypesCount = viewModel?.sectionTypes.count
    else { return 0 }
    return sectionTypesCount
}
```

**TableView NumberOfRowsInSection:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let sectionType = viewModel?.sectionTypes[section]
    else { return 0 }
    
    switch sectionType {
    case .filter:
        return 1
    case .stock(let myPageDefaults):
        return myPageDefaults.count
    }
}
```

**TableView Section Reaload:**

I am getting an error while refreshing the section here.

```
if let index = self.viewModel?.sectionTypes.firstIndex(where: { if case .stock = $0 { return true }; return false }) {
    let section = [index]
    let indexSet = IndexSet(section)
    self.tableView.reloadSections(indexSet, with: .fade)
    self.viewModel?.refreshService2EverySecond()
} else {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.viewModel?.refreshService2EverySecond()
}
```

**Assigment .stock Cell:**

here I assigned the `.stock` section. I'm not removing the .stock section. I just asigned the new data.

```
if let index = self.sectionTypes.firstIndex(where: { if case .stock = $0 { return true }; return false }) {
    self.sectionTypes[index] = .stock(l.map({self.makeRowForMyPageDefault(with: $0)}))
} else {
    self.sectionTypes.append(.stock(l.map({self.makeRowForMyPageDefault(with: $0)})))
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the viewModel?.sectionTypes.count is changing from 2 to 1 when the response comes from the API?